# Ordering of events when printing/pdf-ing from iCal

Tags: pdf, calendar, ical, printing

Spent a few hours searching on Google and in other forums - I know this issue has come up before, but I couldn't find a single answer or solution anywhere.

It seems that when I go to print the calendar (or turn it into a PDF) it decides to completely randomly re-order my events. There seems to be no rhyme or reason to it. In iCal they are in a perfectly logical, organized order.  When I go to print, they appear randomly mixed around.

I have attached some photos: The first is from iCal, second is what the pdf looks like. Note that not only does it re-order the events from the way they appear in iCal, but the way it is re-ordering the events appears to be changing at random from day to day: compare the blue events on the 17th and 24th in image 2 - these events are repeating weekly events and were not entered into the calendar manually. There is absolutely nothing different about the events on the 17<sup>th</sup> and the 24<sup>th</sup>, yet they appear in a different order on each of those days. The orange events are not repeating events and were each entered manually on their given days, but they too are being re-ordered randomly from day to day. I've noticed that this isn't just an issue for all-day events - the exact same problem occurs when multiple events occur at the same time (8am, for example).

Has this just been accepted as an unfixable issue? Super frustrated, spent hours putting a year-long call schedule together for my residency program only to find it's a confusing mess when I try to print it or turn it into a PDF. If there is no solution, does anyone have suggestions for an easy to use app that I *can* use to generate a PDF calendar that looks similar?

[image: Calendar.app]

[image: PDF]

I am using a MacBook Pro with 10.7.5 installed.

Comment: How do you turn them into PDF?

Comment: File > Print > select the months and calendars you want to print > Continue > bottom left corner there is a tab where you can make a PDF.  This is for iCal in 10.7.5.

Answer (score 1):

I have resorted to taking a screen shot of the full page view of my calendar using command-shift-3.  This saves the screen image to your desktop.  The image isn't as nice and bright, but it is in the proper order.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your calendar in iCal
2. Open a specific date in 'Day View'
3. On the right hand side, you will see the date the events are taking place.
4. For each of your events, click on this date, it will bring up a red 'all-day' check box.
5. Uncheck this, then check it again.

Do this for each event in the order that you would like them to appear, so the first unchecked/checked event will appear on top and the last unchecked/checked event will appear at the bottom.

You can see if this has worked by by going to File > Print. iCal orders the all-day events according to which was entered first, second, third. Sometimes further modifications to the calendar can throw it all out again.

[image: Day view of events- click on the date on the right hand side- in this example, would be Friday 20 Aug]

[image: Uncheck, then Check 'All-day' box]